# MSI 970A-G43 with FX-6300 and MSI HD 7850 won't POST or display anything or make any noise

Tags: hardware-failure, computer-building, post

This is my build: http://pcpartpicker.com/p/269CL

I have connected everything, and even reseated the graphics card and the ram after the first time it failed, but my motherboard won't POST or display anything on the monitor. I have tried connecting via both DVI and VGA. All the fans are spinning, the GPU one, the CPU heatsink, and the one in the PSU. I'm trying to test it outside the case first with only the GPU, the CPU, the heatsink, and the PSU connected. I turn it on by shorting the power button connector with a screwdriver, and that part works fine, but it's not outputting anything nor making any noise(actually I don't have a speaker, so it can't make any noise).

Comment: Just to be sure - you have plugged in power to the video card, correct? The six pin plug.

Comment: Yes, I have. As well as the 24-pin and the 6 pin ATX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power to the motherboard was about 1 mm away from completely socketed, and with a lot of effort, I fixed it.